# How to integrate USSD?

Tags: android, ussd

How to integrate USSD in android application? How can I display my own data in ussd dialog box after calling specific ussd code without using any http connection or internet ?

Comment: See this Repo https://github.com/arfawy/USSD/tree/master/app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Android API for USSD. You may be able to find some hack that will work on some devices and some dialer apps, but there is no general way to use USSD.